Frustrating IntelliJ build failure - JCTree$JCImport does not have member field JCTree qualid
I am building a Spring Boot project in IntelliJ, and getting a build error:
"com.sun.tools.javac.JCTree$JCImport does not have member field JCTree qualid"

I have no references to that class in my project. I checked ChatGPT and it advised that it could be due to a Lombok version issue, but there are no dependencies at all to Lombok in my effective pom.
I tried using Java 21 and then Java 11.
I tried invalidating caches, repairing IDE, nada
I also tried recreating the project from sources.
Nothing helps!
When I build from Maven, everything builds and runs correctly.
I don't know if this is an IntelliJ issue or something with my env, but I suspect IntelliJ since it is working with Maven, same versions of everything.
Anyone see this before? Any advice?

This question is similar to: Compilation error after upgrading to JDK 21 - "NoSuchFieldError: JCImport does not have member field JCTree qualid". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
